# Html - Prevent other submission events while ONE submission is in process?

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I have a form with two buttons - submitSave and submitProcessed.

submitSave will trigger code to create an entry in database with status="saved".
submitProcessed will look for that entry created previously and execute additional logic. If it can't find any entry, it will create a new entry.

What happened to some of the test cases is that sometimes a user clicks submitSave button and the database is still in the middle of creating that entry. Then the user quickly click the submitProcessed button again - because the previous entry is not yet available in the table, it creates a duplicate entry.

Any idea on how to handle this so it will not create duplicate entry in the table? I am thinking to disable the other button once one button is clicked.

Comment: And what did you try so far? share your code.

Answer (score 3):

hide the submitProcessed and show it once the submitSave has finished processing

Second option:
On submitSave click set a variable 'processing' to yes and no when done

when someone clicks the submitProcessed button it will check if the variable status is yes or no and will carry out the tasks accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Overlay the screen with a div that sits on top of everything (z-index) to stop clicks from happening. Once your process completes remove this overlay.
2. Disable the buttons you don't want users clicking until they are allowed to click them.
3. Use a semaphore variable to tell you when to allow or stop clicks from happening. Once a click happens set the variable to something that tells other clicks they can't process until this variable says they can.
4. Hide the buttons you don't want users to click until they are allowed to click them.